# Index Column in Temp Table

Tags: sql, indexing, sql-server-2012, temp-tables

I have a table with multiple Items and about twenty conditions
I'm trying to group those conditions and give each condition ID

Here is incorrect or I would say pseudo code:

> Create Table #IndexCondition
>
> (
>
> Select id int identity(1, 1) not null,
> Condition
> From Items
> Group
> By Condition
> )

So output should have two Columns:
One is **ConditionID**, Second **Condition**

Comment: Can you explain a little bit further??? and which version of SQL you are using. eg MySQL, MS SQL, Oracle

Comment: Really Which version. It says in the tag sql-server-2012. which is ms sql